# ContextMenu hide after an item is clicked

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

when I click on an item of this ContextMenu, my application works fine but the ContextMenu appears till process completed.

How can I hide it after clicking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you're executing too much code in UI and blocking the UI thread. UI thread hasn't been relieved yet. Only when you release the UI thread, it will be able to close the popup menu.

All you've to do is to offload time consuming task to some other thread and keep the UI thread free. Using [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the recommended way of offloading tasks. Take a look at `Task.Run` and `Task.Factory.StartNew` methods.